# How do you reset the value of an Azure DevOps input variable?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

How do you reset the value of an Azure DevOps `Get-VstsInput` variable?

I'm running the PowerShell script from a custom task locally to check it's working as expected ...

```
Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock { . ..\buildAndReleaseTask\main.ps1 }
```

The first time I run the script, I get the prompts for various values. The script gets input using the SDK function [Get-VstsInput](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Commands.md#get-vstsinput).

But on subsequent runs of the script, the values are already set.
However I can't see any indication in the docs on how you can reset the value.

The code starts with getting the required values, which the user has filled in on the Azure DevOps pipeline dialog ...

```
$serverName= Get-VstsInput -Name "serverName" -Require
```

I've checked the environment variables, but nothing there.

The only solution I've found is to close my PowerShell console.

Comment: without seeing the code in question, this is a WildAssGuess ... have you properly initialized the $Vars? is the path a $Var passes thru ever such that you use the $Var without 1st setting it to a known value such as `$Null` or `<blank>`?

Comment: Having a little trouble grasping what you are meaning, but maybe glance through this [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) on settings variables using some commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> For the convenience of interactive testing, the module will prompt for undefined task variables and inputs. For example, Get-VstsTaskInput -Name SomeVariable will prompt for the value if the task variable is not defined. If a value is entered, then it will be stored so that subsequent calls will return the same value. Task variables are stored as environment variables. **Inputs and endpoints are stored internally within the VstsTaskSdk module and can be cleared by removing and re-importing the module.**

So calling `Remove-Module VstsTaskSdk` should do the trick.

Instead of relying on the interactive mode I tend to set my variables and inputs through environment variables, that makes them easier to change and works the same between the Node and the Powershell handlers:

```
# Task variable 'Build.SourcesDirectory':
$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY = [...]

# Input 'MyInput':
$env:INPUT_MYINPUT = [...]

# Endpoint:
$env:INPUT_MYENDPOINT = 'EP1'
$env:ENDPOINT_URL_EP1 = 'https://[...]'
$env:ENDPOINT_AUTH_EP1 = '{ "Parameters": { "UserName": "Some user", "Password": "Some password" }, "Scheme": "Some scheme" }'
$env:ENDPOINT_DATA_EP1 = '{ "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2" }'
```

See also:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/TestingAndDebugging.md

Comment: Ah ha ... the Remove-Module trick was the answer I needed. I've been using Get-VstsInput rather than Get-VstsTaskInput and it seems to store the values in a hash table, rather than in environment variables. I'm still puzzled how the Get-Input method becomes Get-VstsInput

Comment: There is a default command prefix defined here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/VstsTaskSdk/VstsTaskSdk.psd1

Comment: If you put them in the environment, the task will pick it up. If you don't it will pop up a dialog and store the values internally. Inputs need to be defined as `INPUT_*` all caps, replace any non alphanumeric character with `_`.